# Jasmine .calls.count and .calls.any throwing error

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test `.calls.count()` and `.calls.any`, I tried the below code from this link [Jasmine test cases](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

```html
describe("A spy", function() {
  var foo, bar = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      setBar: function(value) {
        bar = value;
      }
    };

    spyOn(foo, 'setBar');
  });



  it("tracks if it was called at all", function() {
    expect(foo.setBar.calls.any()).toEqual(false);

    foo.setBar();

    expect(foo.setBar.calls.any()).toEqual(true);
  });



  it("tracks the number of times it was called", function() {
    expect(foo.setBar.calls.count()).toEqual(0);

    foo.setBar();
    foo.setBar();

    expect(foo.setBar.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
  });

});
```

But this throws error saying:

> TypeError: 'foo.setBar.calls.any' is not a function

and

> TypeError: 'foo.setBar.calls.count' is not a function

I checked the syntax, it's same everywhere on the net. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a silly question, but are you sure you're not accidentally using Jasmine 1.3? `calls` was a valid property there too, but it didn't yet have the `any()` and `count()` methods, which you're referencing in the 2.0 docs.

(I've faced a lot of similar mistakes while migrating from 1.3 to 2.0, because the syntax is very similar, so the mistakes don't stand out at a glance.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out ,I am actually using jasmine 1.3

Comment: Another silly question , as I am new to jasmine kindly tell me steps to upgrade it 2.0 as I didn't anything on the net

Comment: Just replace the 1.3 source files with the 2.0 source files. OR if you're using a dependency management tool like bower, just change the declared dependency number to 2.0 in your bower.json descriptor, then run bower prune then bower install.

Comment: Just another thing suppose we want see how many times a function was called we will write : 
expect(<some obj>.<some method>.callCount).toEqual(1);
But if i want to know how many times a method was called with particulars arguments :
expect(<some obj>.<some method>).toHaveBeenCalledWith("arg","arg2"); Is it possible to check how many times this was called?

Comment: @YepMe I'm sure you can do that manually using the call history available (through `calls`), but I don't know of a built-in way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and then looked up this. The answer above is right, and I managed to fix it by explicitly including a reference to "jasmine2" in my testem.json, instead of just "jasmine":

```
{
   "framework": "jasmine2",
   "src_files": [
      "filePath1.js",
      "filePath2.js",
      "filePathEtc.js"
   ]
}
```